# Permissions required for the DATA folder

Tags: sql-server, file-permissions, ntfs

I have Sql Server 2017 and the Data folder is the default at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL`. The access rights on the folder are:

[image]

I have an old database with its MDF file in `My SQL Database`. I tried to duplicate the same rights to `My SQL Database`:

[image]

I couldn't duplicate those for ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES as I don't know who it is.

With the above rights on `My SQL Database` I couldn't reattach a database from its MDF file in that folder. It keeps saying `Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"` on the MDF file.

What access permissions are required to have database files in another folder other than the default?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I am also getting the same error.

Comment: No. Did you try the solution given in the answer by Ezlo?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services
```

And check the value of `service_account` for the `servicename` thats `SQL SERVER`:

[image]

Then make sure that the folder ***and the files*** have the proper access rights for that account.

Comment: Yes, it is `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` and this account already has Full access to the folder.

Comment: Give access directly to the file, not (just) the folder. You might not be propagating the rights to subfolders/files or have another policy in check.

Answer (score 1):

Add your user account in Advanced Security Setting of the Data folder with Full Control access
[image]